# FPV-Camera Input in Black and White / losses Color on conversion with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-capture, linux, rtmp

so we're working on our end-of-school project and it's an FPV-Drone with an Analogue Camera on it. Plan is to send the video feed to a Raspberry Pi running an RTMP-Server from where a Phone-Application can view the live Video of the camera.

To convert this analogue Data from the camera we use a USB2.0 Grabber (this one).

To create the RTMP Stream from the converted USB-Input we use FFMPEG with the following command:

> fmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -preset ultrafast -b:v 2000k -fflags nobuffer -rtmp_live live -f flv rtmp://192.168.8.107:554/live/stream

It works fine, but the main problems at the moment are:

- the video is in Black and White
  [B&W Image Stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEonJ.png)
- the stream has a delay of 10-20s depending on the network

When I'm using the official Software provided by the Reseller I had the same problem, but as soon as it set PAL/BDGHI in the Settings the colour was shown correctly:

[Settings and Color Image in official software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ss99.jpg)

the video is in Black and White

Does anyone know what settings there are to correctly decode the feed from the Camera and send the video with the colour over RTMP? I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I'm running out of ideas and every single decoder I have tried apart from the ones I'm currently using does not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**Nevermind someone on Reddit found the problem:**

https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/18or1xt/fpv_camera_input_in_black_and_white_help/

Comment: Nevermind someone on Reddit found the problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/18or1xt/fpv_camera_input_in_black_and_white_help/